# Using multiple instances of SQL Workbench/J

Tags: sql-workbench-j

How to open multiple instances of "SQL Workbench/J" or connect to multiple Database Instances?

Answer (score 3):

You can open multiple windows that use different connection profiles.

Start SQL Workbench/J, connect to one database, then use "File -> New Window" to open another window. You can connect with a different connection profile in that window.